# Laravel 5.4 Update method and uploading files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I would like in the method **update()** to upload files to the server.

upload method:

```
    private function upload($request){
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $generate_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        $file_name = $generate_name . '.' . $extension;
        $image->move(public_path() . '/post_image/', $file_name);
        return $file_name;
    }
}
```

update method:

```
    public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $id)
{
    $article = Article::FindOrFail($id);

    $file = $this->upload($request);
    $article->image = $file;

    $article->update($request->all());

    Session::flash('message', 'Wpis został edytowany!');

    return redirect('articles');
}
```

However, when I send the form error occurs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1azI.png)

But the same code with the upload () method store works very well.

```
    public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = new Article($request->all());

    $file = $this->upload($request);
    $article->image = $file;

    Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);
    Session::flash('message', 'Wpis został dodany!');
    return redirect('articles');
}
```

Comment: POst the errors not  a picture of the errors

Comment: Are you using same form for both events(create&update)? Can you post your form here to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just got this issue and fixed it using `Input::all` instead of `$request` object, something like:

```
$data = Input::all();
if(isset($data['image'])) {
    ... // Do your thing
}
```

It seems like there is any issue with the `request` helper/class and the `UploadedFile` when you make `PUT` instead of pure `POST`

Cheers!!...

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the update method. I've been through this, my solution was this. See if you solve your problem.

```
 public function save(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();

        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $image = $request->file('file');

            $num = rand(1234,8976);
            $dir ="img/courses/";
            $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $nameImage = "image".$num.".".$ext;

            $image->move($dir,$nameImage);
            $data['image'] = $dir."/".$nameImage;
        }

        YoutClass::create($dados);

        return redirect()->route('ROUTE');

    }
```

Comment: Please be careful while overriding any framework method as it may have unexpected results. always use `return parent::save();` to make sure your logic goes through the framework as well.